# Add <span> tag just after outside <a> tag using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Hello everyone i just want to add `<span>` after `<a>` tag . This is the demo of adding `<span>` tag inside the `<a>` tag

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upbx2jv4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `after` to add element after the selector.

```
$('a').after("<span>DEmo</span>");
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/upbx2jv4/1/

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/after/